# polynomial fitting for unseen data

Tags: r

orignally i have the data in the form

```
m n
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16
```

using the following code i convert it to

```
input<-file('stdin', 'r')

mn <- read.table(input, nrows = 1, as.is = TRUE)

DF <- read.table(input, skip = 0)



m <- mn[[1]]

n <- mn[[2]]

x1<- DF[[1]]

y1<-DF[[2]]

x2<-DF[[3]]

y2<-DF[[4]]

fit1<-lm(x1 ~ poly(y1, 3, raw=TRUE))

fit2<-lm(x2 ~ poly(y2, 3, raw=TRUE))
```

`

m = the current datas length

n = number of points in the future to be predicted

```
x1=  1  5  9 13

x2= 2 6 10 14
```

i would like to predict all the values of x1  y1 x2 y2 for n values after the given values.

i tried to fit with lm but i am not sure how to proceed with all the values of   data points to be predicted in the future missing and just getting the coefficients in terms of the other would not be sufficient as all of them need to be predicted